# equals comparison for 2 objects in Java 7

Tags: java, object, equals

```
public class ObjectEqualsComparison {
      public static void main(String[] args) {      
           Object ob1 = new Object();  // address location 0×1234 
           Object ob2 = new Object();  // address location 0×2345 

           System.out.println(ob1 == ob2); // prints false correct
           System.out.println(ob1.equals(ob2)); //prints false which is incorrect//it should be true.

           //ob1 == ob2 gives false which is correct since you are comparing address/references .
           //ob1.equals(ob2) is also giving false.can you tell me why since we are comparing contents       
        }
}
```

**EDIT::My question is do i need to override equals() method.if so how should the equals() overriden method look like. Please help**

Comment: There are hundreds of questions about equals vs. == on Stack Overflow.  Please use the search facility before posting.

Comment: You cannot override `equals()` on the `Object` class.

Comment: i could not find for objects.Sorry

Comment: `prints false which is incorrect` is an incorrect assertion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `System.out.println(ob1.equals(ob2));` is correct because you are comparing instances of type `object`. If you were comparing instances of a type that overrides `equals` then that would be a different story!

For example, if you have:

```
class SomeType{

    private Object comparisonField;

    public SomeType(Object comparisonValue){
        this.comparisonField = comparisonValue;
    }

    @overrides
    public int getHashCode(Object other){
        if(this.comparisonField == null)
            return super.getHashCode();

        return this.comparisonField.getHashCode();
    }

    @overrides
    public boolean equals(Object other){
        if(comparisonField == null || other == null)
           return super.equals(other);

        return comparisonField.equals(((SomeType)other).comparisonField);
    }
}
```

When comparing:

```
SomeType inst1 = new SomeType("SAME VALUE");
SomeType inst2 = new SomeType("SAME VALUE");

bool areEqual = inst1.equals(inst2);  // calls the overriden equals method on SomeType
                                      //   which would return TRUE 

// but if you use object:

Object obj1 = new Object();
Object obj2 = new Object();

bool areEqual = obj1.equals(obj2);    // will call equals on Object;
                                      //   and always return false;
```

Comment: If you were comparing instances of a type that overrides equals then that would be a different story!,any example please

Comment: Try it with String. `String` has an overriden `equals` method.

Comment: but im case if i wanted both ob1 and ob2 to be equal.what shoould i do

Comment: if `ob1` and `ob2` are of type `Object` they will only be equal if they are references to the same instance! Otherwise you need to be more specific about which types you are comparing.. Being more specific means casting them to an appropriate type.

Comment: Miky,could you let me the code which i need to insert in              public bool equals(Object other){
        // put logic to compare two instances of SomeType here           
    }

Comment: getting an error at  base and @overrides.help providded will be appreciated Miky

Comment: sorry.. C# syntax.. it should have been `super.equals`

Comment: well do i need to also override hashcode method ?how would that look like?,Miky dont say sorry,this amswer is possible because of your extended efforts.Thanks :-))

Comment: @Deepak - please see update. That said, the implementations of `getHashCode()` as well as `equals(...)` I gave are just examples. You will have to determine the logic that is appropriate for your own types. The idea behind implementing `getHashCode` along with `equals` is to ensure that two instances that test equal also return the same hash code.

Comment: @Miky i guess the getHashcode method is incorrect,could you check it once

Comment: public int getHashCode(Object other){
          if(this.comparisonField == null)
               return super.getHashCode();
        return this.comparisonField.getHashCode();
    }
 This method is showing an incorrect signature,say no method like getHashCode and does not accept arguments.

Comment: @Deepak please ask a separate question and provide as many details as possible. This is not how SO works!

Answer (score 1):

The default implementation of equals() found in Object will return true only if the 2 objects are the same instance, i.e. the same object in memory.  Any time you create 2 separate Object instances as you did, they do not reference the same object in memory which is why it returns false.

As Miky pointed out, you can modify that default behavior to provide custom equivalency semantics by overriding equals() in your class.

However, Miky is incorrect in that casting your class (e.g. your SomeType instance in his example) to Object will change the outcome of equals().

```
boolean areEqual = obj1.equals(obj2);
```

will still invoke the overridden equals() method defined by SomeType regardless of the fact that it is being referenced generically as its supertype, Object.  That's the power of polymorphism.

So, to answer your original question, you have to create your own class and the override equals() in that class with an implementation that performs whatever equivalency checks are meaningful for your class.  For example, if you have a Customer class and customers are defined uniquely by their email address, then in Customer.equals(), you'd compare email addresses and return true if they are the same.

Keep in mind that the signature of equals() accepts an Object argument. A properly constructed equals implementation will check if the argument is null and if it's an instance of the same type.  Also be aware that you MUST override hashCode() when you override equals().

There is a ton of information easily found about overriding equals() and hashCode() that I suggest you research more.  A good place to start is always the "Effective Java" book.

Comment: +1 - you were right about the object cast..